# How to find if JDK7 is compatible with my Project's JARs

Tags: java-7, compatibility

We are in the process of upgrading our project to JDK7 and I have a huge list of third party JARs (450+) being used. I can open each individual website and check if that version is compatible with JDK7 or not but wanted to check if there is a smarter and quicker way to verify this... like if there is a tool which can help, or a website...Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: You should upgrade to JDK 8.  JDK 7 is approaching end of support in April 2015 so you're just setting yourself up to repeat this pain...

Comment: Some organization don't have frequent update cycles specially banking and financials one .One way would be get a machine install jdk7 .install maven to use jdk7 then in the project folder run mvn versions:display-dependency-updates that will tell all the jars which needs update.Given your project has maven

Comment: Thanks for the comment Foosh! Can you pls tell me if there is any way I can verify my JARs for JDK 8 then? See, my thing is, in anyway, I need to verify the JAR compatibility before upgradation.